# How to create a Word Cloud from a large html file using Python?

Tags: python, html, numpy, beautifulsoup

I have a very large but single html file from which I'd like to build a word cloud. I have BeautifulSoup, Wordcloud, numpy and matplotlib installed, but many of the guides out there deal with urls. I just need to parse a local file and work from there.

Any advice on how to get started?

Comment: This is too vague/broad.

Answer (score 0):

Following the [documentation](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#making-the-soup) you can simply pass beautifulsoup an open file:

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

with open("index.html") as fp:
    soup = BeautifulSoup(fp)

soup = BeautifulSoup("<html>data</html>")
```

Then after that you should be able to follow any tutorial.